# How to send money to an IBAN bank number from a Mastercard?

Tags: credit-card, international-transfer, mastercard, iban

I have to pay 1600 Euros for some building work in France where I live, and my french banks are too empty, I have to borrow it from my MasterCard which is still based in the UK. If I call the UK it costs 5-10 pounds for the call and perhaps they'll turn me down, and they don't have online chat (Halifax bank).

Can I walk into the French bank and hand them a Mastercard and say "please credit this IBAN with 1600 euros"?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three options.

1. Withdraw the money from your mastercard at an ATM ("cash advance") and deposit it do your french current account from which you can initiate a transfer to the IBAN account to pay (this option likely includes cash advance and FX fees)
2. Use fintech services such as `Revolut` that allow you to bind credit cards, withdraw money from them without being recognized as "cash advance", then use the app to convert it from GBP to EUR & transfer it from within the app to the IBAN account (this method does not incur any fees)
3. Same as (2) but using Western Union, which has a cap on credit card withdrawals and incurs significant fees

*Note: I am not affiliated with Revolut in any way*